# Memory leak when re-logging into the iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks

In one of my application I am presenting a landing view controller as shown in the code. This works fine except for the fact that when I logout of the application and re-login, the same method gets called and it end up creating a new `MyLandingController` keeping the old one still hanging around. Since, I am assigning it to a property shouldn't it get auto de-allocate old one? I checked and ensured that there is no other object keep a strong reference to `MyLandingController`; there are weak references though.

```
- (void)presentMyLandingView {
    self.navigationController = nil;
    [[self.window viewWithTag:100] removeFromSuperview];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.primaryViewController = [[MyLandingController alloc] init];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.primaryViewController];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    [self.window insertSubview:[self.navigationController view] atIndex:1];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.50 target:self selector:@selector(clearSubviews) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

As a temporary work around, I thought of putting a condition that if my older `MyLandingController` exists then use that instead of creating a new one. That fixes the leak but entire view is moved up (looks like moved up by navigation bar size).

So, I am looking for answer to 2 questions here -

Q1) Why is re-initializing a new view controller object to a property not de-allocating older object.

Q2) Why re-using the existing object (pulled from a weak reference) not rendering the UI well - screen moves up?

Comment: why are you not making nill to Navigation controller & self.primaryViewController as well. Navigation controller is taking place here.

Comment: Already tried - No luck!

Answer (score 1):

It leaks because the landing controller is still in the presentation stack, so it does not get deallocated -- the navigation controller still holds a reference.

That - by coincidence - answers both your questions, as a view controller should not be in the presentation stack twice.

You could check if it exists and in that case just

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

instead of creating another instance.

Comment: Thank you Jan! As I mentioned, I tried that and it fixes the leak but then my landing view does not load well. Entire view moves up by around 64 pt.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using for that? Seems like you are misusing one technique or another, hard to guess. Are you by any chance manipulating any frames in the controller's `viewDidLoad` that should be in `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: I am having a weak reference of `MyLandingController` into a singleton session class and then use it instead of creating a new one to set as rootViewController for window object.

Comment: Something like this -> `self.primaryViewController = MySessionObject.landingController ?: [[MyLandingController alloc] init];`

Comment: Do not re-set the root view controller, just let the navigationController pop back. Maybe have a read on the concept of view controllers and the presentation stack. And try to interact with the window as less as possible. Can you update your question to show more context?

Answer (score 0):

Memory leak exists because of the last line:

`[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.50 target:self selector:@selector(clearSubviews) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];`

`NSTimer` keeps strong reference to its target before it is invalidated. From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:):

> The object to which to send the message specified by aSelector when the timer fires. The timer maintains a strong reference to this object until it (the timer) is invalidated.

You have to invalidate your old timer before you create a new one in order to get rid of the memory leak.

```
 - (void)presentMyLandingView {
      [self.timer invalidate]; //invalidates the old timer 
      //rest of your code goes here
      self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.50 target:self selector:@selector(clearSubviews) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]; //keeps reference to the new timer so that it is possible to invalidate that timer later . Note that this should be a `weak` reference as the timer is retained by the run loop anyway.
 }
```

Comment: That's not true. Two things here - first, this timer is non-repeat timer so it vanishes once done and so the strong reference, second, timer is on AppDelegate which is not causing leak. MyLandingController is leaking here. Moreover, as I mentioned, leak gets fixed if I reuse the earlier created object but then after re-login, it's UI is not completely shown; in fact view starts from the place where status bar starts.